# Fully qualified domain name for gitlab

Tags: nginx, gitlab

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 with Gitlab installed. I Don't really know what is mean with the fully qualified domain host name. Until now I have test gitlab locally in my network with a **static** ip `192.168.1.x`. But I want get access to my raspberry pi from the outside. I have registered a host at `no-ip.com`. Now, what should I write in the `/etc/hosts`, `/etc/hostname`, `config/gitlab.yml`, `gitlab-shell/config.yml` and in the `nginx` config? Just the xx.no-ip.org address? I also want use ssl for this. Here's something to be observed?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You "only" need to write the no-ip.com hostname into your gitlab and nginx configuration (nginx doesn't care too much with the gitlab-ssl configuration but it's a good habit that is required in bigger setups). You do not need to write them to /etc/hosts and /etc/hostname.
The main use for this is that the webserver and gitlab knows a) service is requested (nginx) or it should link to (gitlab).

Beside this your internet router needs to forward a from the internet reachable port to port 443 (https) on your raspberry pi. How to do this highly depends on your system. If you forward port 80 on your router to port 80 on your RPi: this is fine as long as you use the nginx-ssl configuration file (else connections will be insecure).